# HTTP caching and ETAG header

Tags: caching, nginx, varnish, etag

After a lot of unsuccessful research, I'm wondering if it's possible to use nginx or varnish cache function to check data freshness it contains using etag attribute in the header.

This scenario is easier to explain with a diagram, please see below :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/49/1417684577-cache-nginx.png

Do you think this use case is feasible ?

Thank you and sorry for my english :s

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar with varnish, [stale-while-revalidate](https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/grace-varnish-4-stale-while-revalidate-semantics-varnish), but not quite the same. The idea with the front caches is that when the backend sends an object to the cache it sets an Expires header that will allow the cache to serve this content without bothering the backend. If the cache would check every request with the backend then there wouldn't be much speed to gain, as you would end up waiting for the backend on each request.

To solve this, you should set your Expires headers accordingly, and/or purge/ban the urls if suddenly you need to get rid of stale content before Expires. That way the cache would send the content from its own cache, or get from the backend if it doesn't have it or it's stale.

Edit:

I have tested with Varnish 4.0.1, it supports conditional requests to the backend.

My test setup has been an Apache virtual hosts with `ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 seconds"`

The result:

```
*   << BeReq    >> 65539
-   Begin          bereq 65538 bgfetch
-   Timestamp      Start: 1418403624.141695 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /prueba.html
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: lwp-request/6.03 libwww-perl/6.05
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: localtest
-   BereqHeader    Surrogate-Capability: key=ESI/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    If-Modified-Since: Thu, 01 Dec 2011 10:37:55 GMT
-   BereqHeader    If-None-Match: "3e8be5-46-4b30571f606c0"
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 65539
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Backend        17 vdir server1(127.0.0.1,,80)
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1418403624.141869 0.000174 0.000174
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1418403624.143205 0.001510 0.001336
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   304
-   BerespReason   Not Modified
-   BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 17:00:24 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache
-   BerespHeader   ETag: "3e8be5-46-4b30571f606c0"
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 17:00:29 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=5
-   TTL            RFC 5 -1 -1 1418403624 1418403624 1418403624 1418403629 5
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Dec 2011 10:37:55 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL 5 21600 0 1418403624
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      200
-   ObjReason      OK
-   ObjHeader      Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 17:00:24 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Server: Apache
-   ObjHeader      ETag: "3e8be5-46-4b30571f606c0"
-   ObjHeader      Expires: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 17:00:29 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=5
-   ObjHeader      Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Dec 2011 10:37:55 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html
-   BackendReuse   17 server1(127.0.0.1,,80)
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1418403624.143465 0.001770 0.000260
-   Length         70
-   BereqAcct      289 0 289 181 0 181
-   End
```

Here you can see that I ask for a stale object, so varnish goes to fetch it, and request it this way:

```
-   BereqURL       /prueba.html
-   BereqHeader    If-Modified-Since: Thu, 01 Dec 2011 10:37:55 GMT
-   BereqHeader    If-None-Match: "3e8be5-46-4b30571f606c0"
```

The backend answers with:

```
-   BerespStatus   304
-   BerespReason   Not Modified
-   BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 17:00:24 GMT
-   BerespHeader   ETag: "3e8be5-46-4b30571f606c0"
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Fri, 12 Dec 2014 17:00:29 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=5
```

So no body bytes are transferred, and varnish refreshes it's object with the newly updated headers.

Perhaps that's the behavior you wanted.

Keep in mind that a `GET` request that does validate the conditions (`If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match`) would only return a `304 Not Modified`, some headers and no body (exactly the same as if it would be a `HEAD` request with the same conditions), if it doesn't validate it will return the headers and the new body. But a `HEAD` requests that does not validate would return `200 OK`, and **NO** body, forcing you to re-request it with a GET.

[HTTP/1.1 Method Definitions RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation
>   contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be
>   identical to the information sent in response to a GET request.

Comment: The idea was the cache could check via a HEAD call the value in the etag attribute of each asked ressource before sending it to the client. In this way the customer is sure to have an updated version of the requested resource. Do you think it's a good approach ? Thx.

Comment: I understand, varnish at least won't do that by default if it has an object in the cache still valid. I will send its own cache version without checking. The problem with doing a HEAD on each and every request is that you will still end up waiting for the backend server, so then, why would you want to put a cache in front?

Comment: I thought a HEAD wasn't as ressource intensive for the backend, at least less than a GET call. This cache could be helpfull for not sending the whole response from the backend to the client but just compare ressources freshness. Am i wrong ?

Comment: It depends :). Really, it depends on what does the backend. For example, suppose the resource is a dynamically generated image, and the request the cache does is "GET /image If-Modified-Since: 5 minutes ago", the backend might be smart and seeing that there is no new data it might reply with a 304 not modified. Another request "GET /image If-None-Match: "random etag"" then it depends on how does the backend generate the etag, is it a hash of the generated image? then it has to regenerate it again (or read from a cached file), perhaps a hash of the data used, ... You get the idea.

Comment: OK. Indeed the etag attribute (or any another attribute) could be "manually" associated with à version number of a ressource ? In this case, the cache could check wether the backend ressource's etag is the same that the ressource's etag it contains ? Another way to do that could be first I call the cache, if the ressource isn't expired then cached ressource is sent, if expired, head call to the backend and check etag, if etag is the same extend expiry in the cache, if not then reload. Am I clear ?

Comment: Probably you could do that in vcl, but I haven't tried to work this way. Instead I would put a far away Expires timeout for varnish and purge when needed. The logic you propose works assuming that the resource it's expensive to generate but somehow cheap to validate, that's not the usual case.

Comment: I thought validation could be done with a head call on the ressource and then just compare etag values. I'm wondering if it's possible to compare this two things in vcl_bakcend_response : bereq.http.If-None-Match == beresp.http.Etag ?